# Creating a backup script for database in php

Tags: php, sql, database, backup

I want to create a script,to create a backup for every table of a database.Until now i have this:

Connection to database:

```
<?php
$AdresaBD="localhost";
$UtilizatorBD="root";
$NumeBD="auth";
$NumeBD1="auth1";
$ParolaBD="";


$con1=mysqli_connect($AdresaBD,$UtilizatorBD,$ParolaBD,$NumeBD);
$con2=mysqli_connect($AdresaBD,$UtilizatorBD,$ParolaBD,$NumeBD1);
if( mysqli_connect_errno() ) {
    echo 'Nu ma pot conecta la baza de date!'.mysqli_connect_errno();
}
?>
```

The script:

```
<?php
//auth
$backup1 = fopen('auth_back_'.date('j-M-Y').'.sql','w+');
$CerereSQL = "SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '$backup1' FROM `angajati`,`concedii`";
$result = mysqli_query($con1,$CerereSQL);

//auth1
$backup2 = fopen('auth1_back_'.date('j-M-Y').'.sql','w+');
$CerereSQL = "SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '$backup2' FROM `contact`,`persoane_active`";
$result = mysqli_query($con2,$CerereSQL);
?>
```

(For example,i will choose just a database to explain)I  have  tables angajati,concedii in my database auth , this script should create a backup file sql with those tables,when i test the files to see if they actually have the data inside of them,in other words when i try to import them,it says succes but the data doesnt show up.That's because the files are blank,no matter what i do.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything  as well as `or die(mysqli_error($conX))` to `mysqli_query()`

Comment: Can you post an example of what your .sql file is after you've run this?

Comment: @Fred-ii- , i did it but,it doesnt show any error

Comment: @scrowler you want me to post what's inside of one of my sql files,after its created? or what?

Comment: If your tables and data already exists and nothing changed, then SQL probably won't do anything.

Comment: I deleted my comment about that. Keep it the way it is.

Comment: @Fred-ii- , i already have tables angajati,concedii in my database auth , this script should create a backup file sql with those tables,when i test the files to see if they actually have the data inside of them,in other words when i try to import them,it says succes but the data doesnt show up

Comment: Did you open the file itself from your computer to see if there's actual data in it? Data that seems to be worthy of importing.

Comment: yes,but the file is blank...

Comment: I think the server you're on, doesn't allow that operation from WWW. I added `die(mysqli_error($conn));` and got back access denied for this operation. It may be the same thing for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try and break your code to a simpler version and work up to find the problem.

I'd imagine its a problem with the file your trying to backup to:

- Check the path to file is correct.

**Original Code:**

```
$backup1 = fopen('auth_back_'.date('j-M-Y').'.sql','w+');
$CerereSQL = "SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '$backup1' FROM `angajati`,`concedii`";
$result = mysqli_query($con1,$CerereSQL);
```

**Simplified Code:**

```
$backupFile1 = 'auth_back.sql';
$CerereSQL = "SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '$backupFile1' FROM angajati";
if(mysqli_query($con1,$CerereSQL)) {
    echo 'Database backed up';
}
else {
    echo 'There was an error backing that database up';
}
```